# How to change Gnome (Fedora Linux) main background color?

Tags: linux, fedora, gnome, color-theme, background

How to change Gnome (Fedora 39) theme's main grey background color without changing desktop background image/color?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background color-shading-type 'solid'
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background primary-color '#FFFFFF'
```

https://fostips.com/single-color-background-gnome/